# Reading from a List<string> and writing to csv file - numeric

Tags: c#, string, csv

I am writing a simple application which accepts a type of csv file(always the same format) and the application re-writes another csv file with a different format.

The only issue I am having is the data I am reading contains formatted number amount ex: `2,135,128.69` with commas and when writing this to csv files this is being split. I dont need the number to be comma formatted, I only need the number to be in the same cell when writing to csv file.

with reference to the above example `2,135,128.69`, when using this `searchList[5].Split(',')[6].Replace("\"", "")` is only showing 2 at the moment because it is being split by `,`

Reading csv file

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(openFileDialog1.FileName));
List<string> searchList = new List<string>();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    searchList.Add(line);
}
```

Line 5 - as debugged from array

```
 [5] = "\"\",\"Balance at Period Start\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"2,135,128.69\""
```

writing to csv file:

```
string pathDesktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
var csv = new StringBuilder();

string fileCBS = 
      pathDesktop + "\\TEST_" + DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";

var headerBalancePeriod = 
     string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}", 
                   "", 
                   searchList[5].Split(',')[1].Replace("\"", ""), 
                   "", "", "", "", "", 
                   searchList[5].Split(',') 6].Replace("\"", ""));

csv.AppendLine(headerBalancePeriod);

File.AppendAllText(fileCBS, csv.ToString());
```

Comment: Either remove the commas from the numbers or put double quotes around the numbers.  Often CSV files have double quotes around the fields so the fields can have commas in the data.  There are lots of posts that you can search that solves the issue of reading csv that contain commas inside the double quotes.

Comment: You need to look at CsvHelper => https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: @CodeNotFound If I remember correctly CsvHelpers didn't handle "," case in csv files nor the number case in the question?

Comment: @Carla Fenech this is not well formatted csv. I will give you example 123,123,123,123 How could you parse this into two columns is it [123,123123123] or [123123,123123]... You see the problem

Comment: @FilipCordas so how would you write a number which is formatted 123,123 to a csv file in the same column?

Comment: 1 don't format them with commas CSV is intended to save transport size not be read by people so extra , just adds size to the document. 2use "2,135,128.69" but this will render as string in excel. 3 Use a different separator for columns like | or ; I am not sure how other programs will handle this